# Rails validation scope of serialized text array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails model that has a field `array_field`, which is a serialized text array. I want the combination of this array value and the value of `another_field` to be unique.

Should be straightforward, no?

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :array_field, scope: [:another_field]

  serialize :filters, Array
end
```

This doesn't work. However, if I switch them around in the validations,

`validates_uniqueness_of :another_field, scope: [:array_field]` works as expected.

Can someone explain why this is the case? Is this expected behavior?

The Postgres error for the former setup when `array_field`'s value is `nil` or `[]` is this:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
   LINE 1: ...other_field" = 103 AND "foo"."array_field" = ) LIMIT 1
```

When `array_field` is `[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]` (a sample multiarray I was using), it's:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer
   LINE 1: ...other_field" = 103 AND "foo"."array_field" = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) LIMIT 1
```

It seems that Rails doesn't know how to translate the serialized object for this query. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

**Edit:** This is occurring in Rails 4.0.2.

**Second Edit:**

Clarification: I understand why this is happening (Rails has custom logic for list queries), and I'm using both a custom validator to manually perform the serialization before validating and a custom serializer to avoid problems with comparisons of Yaml strings (as detailed in my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21884041/1103543)).

At this point I'm mostly just wondering why `validates_uniqueness_of` treats the primary field differently from the `scope` fields, and am hoping someone can shed some light.

Comment: can you specify rails version ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why the validations work one way around, but not the other.

But I think basically your problems are due to the fact that `serialize` only defines that an attribute is to be serialized using Yaml on save and deserialized upon load.

In other words: the only thing you say by doing `serialize :filters, Array` is that

> when saving a Foo, serialize it's filters attribute using Yaml first,
>   when loading a Foo from the DB, make sure that the value of the
>   filters attribute is an Array after deserialization, otherwise raise an exception

It does not affect how queries are constructed. Instead, Rails' usual rules for queries are used. So an array is converted into a comma separated list of numbers. This makes sense for example when constructing a `LIKE` query. This is the reason why the query fails. The DB field is a string but you're trying to compare it to a list.

I haven't used native PostgreSQL array columns with Rails 4, but my guess is that these issues would solved if you used those instead a serialization-type solution. You get the added benefit of being able to search within the contents of arrays on the DB level.

Comment: Not an option: `PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions`

Comment: Please explain what you mean. What exactly did you do when you got this error message?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I can't use native Postgres arrays because Postgres requires its multidimensional arrays to be "rectangular," where mine are not (see the sample array in my original question).