# Rails look up by serialized array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, serialization

I'm trying to perform a Rails lookup based on a serialized array text field (Postgres, if it matters). So:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :arr, Array
end
```

Then:

```
> f = Foo.create!(arr: [[1, 2], [3, 4]])
=> #<Foo id: 1, arr: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]>
> f.arr
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

All's well. But I can't seem to do a lookup based on that field:

```
> Foo.where(arr: [[1, 2], [3, 4]])
=> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer
   "foos"."arr" IN (1, 2, ...
                ^
   HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

It seems Rails is trying to convert it into an IN query. No matter, we know Rails serializes with Yaml (or do we?). So let's try:

```
> Foo.where(arr: [[1, 2], [3, 4]].to_yaml)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Closer inspection seems to lead me towards newlines as the reason why this lookup fails. I could find a way around this with a complex LIKE clause but at that point I think I'm probably headed down the wrong path.

Is there a standard way to look up a model in Rails based on a serialized attribute? (Should I just serialize with something that isn't Yaml?) Many thanks!

Comment: Ugh. Why don't you use PostgreSQL's native array support? Then you can use its support for array indexing too.

Comment: Because I need to store multidimensional arrays of non-square sizes whose dimensions keep changing. My understanding is that Postgres doesn't support that, but definitely let me know if it does.

Either way, I'm not sure Rails will behave correctly in this case.

Comment: Confirmed it's not an option: `PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions`

Comment: That's an excellent reason! I'm so used to people just not considering the database's capabilities...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I'm using for now (definitely open to other approaches!) is to force Rails to serialize with something other than Yaml, to allow for string queries:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :arr, SerializedArray

  def self.find_by_arr
    self.where(arr: SerializedArray.dump(arr)).take
  end
end

class SerializedArray
  def self.load(arr)
    arr ? JSON.load(arr) : nil
  end

  def self.dump(arr)
    arr ? JSON.dump(arr) : nil
  end
end
```

It's a little janky in that I have to query with the custom `find_by_arr`, but it works.

(Edit: removed bad example code.)